# Klarna Module not working Magento2 2.3

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, klarna

When I activate the integrated Klarna module and try to buy items in the shop I get the following error message in the console:

Error: [object Object] customer-data.js:91:23

```
return $.getJSON(options.sectionLoadUrl, parameters).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                throw new Error(jqXHR);
            });
```

The page loads forever and I cannot get to the checkout page.

Comment: Project is in developer mode?

Comment: If my answer is useful to you then accept an answer, so it will be useful to another user. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your project in developer mode then this error appears when I switch from Client-Side to Server-Side Compilation in

> Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Frontend Development Workflow > Workflow type

So **customer-data.js** uses the localStorage within the browser itself to store a variety of information, so you can clear the Magento Cache all you want and you will still have issues.

If you still getting the issue then clear the Local Storage session & Cookies.

**You can clear using the following way:**

1. Google Chrome is hit F12 to open the Developer Toolbar
2. Then select the Application tab. Clear the Local Storage, Session Storage, and Cookies.
3. Reload the page and all should be well.
4. You will have to do this on your admin page as well.

[Click here for more refrance](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6410#issuecomment-243704461)

I hope it helps! Thanks.

Comment: I find difficulty around refreshing placements for configurable products. Could you please help me with it?